# Kivy lenguage: on_key_down

Tags: python, events, kivy, kivy-language

How to I use "on_key_down" event within .kv file?
I have a text input box and I want to detect when a key is pressed down to block user from deleting the first word of the "text" property of my text input to simulate a "bash console" if you will

Answer (score 1):

use the event **on_text** instead.. i don't think on_key_down exists as an event on the input widget